# Clear ViewBag message in MVC3

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, viewbag

I am having a registration form. After successful registration I have to set ViewBag.Msg in controller and displayed it on view. This time all the fields are clear and only
"You have registered successfully" message is there.

Now if I click on Submit then jquery validations are called and error messages like "Required field" are displayed.

But "successful" message is still there. How can I clear this message?

Comment: Yep. We can't possibly answer this without your code.

Answer (score 8):

Use

```
TempData["mesage"]="Hello";
```

instead of

```
ViewBag.Message="Hello";
```

Because `ViewBag` maintain data on refresh also but `TempData` dispose after render once